# Why we are adding an integer value to BIOS variable

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I am going through MSDOS source code and i found some trouble in understanding the code as mentioned below:

```
BIOSSEG:EQU 40H     ; I/O 
;system segment.
BIOSLEN:EQU 2048        ; 
;Maximum length of I/O 
;system.
DOSLEN: EQU 8192        ; 
;Maximum length of MS-DOS.
QSIZE:  EQU 80      ; Input 
;queue size.
PBUFSIZ:EQU 128     ; Size 
;of print buffer
BASE:   EQU 0F0H        ; 
;CPU Support card base port 
;number.
SIOBASE:EQU 10H     ; Base 
;port number of Multiport 
;Serial card.
;STAT:  EQU BASE+7      ; 
;Serial I/O status port.
DATA:   EQU BASE+6      ; 
;Serial I/O data port.
;DAV:   EQU 2       ; Data 
;available bit.
TBMT:   EQU 1       ; 
;Transmitter buffer empty 
;bit.
SERIAL: EQU  
SERIALPRN+SERIALAUX
STCDATA:EQU BASE+4      ; 
;Ports for 9513 Timer chip.
STCCOM: EQU BASE+5

IF  SERIALAUX
AUXSTAT:EQU SIOBASE+3
AUXDATA:EQU SIOBASE+2
ENDIF

IF  PARALLELAUX
AUXSTAT:EQU BASE+13
AUXDATA:EQU BASE+12
ENDIF

IF  SERIALPRN
PRNSTAT:EQU SIOBASE+1
PRNDATA:EQU SIOBASE+0
ENDIF
```

Here we can easily see that we declared BASE value as

```
BASE: EQU 0F0H
```

Later we code as:

```
IF  PARALLELAUX
AUXSTAT:EQU BASE+13
AUXDATA:EQU BASE+12
ENDIF
```

My confusion is that why we are adding 13 to the BASE in the below given code:

```
IF  PARALLELAUX
AUXSTAT:EQU BASE+13
AUXDATA:EQU BASE+12
ENDIF
```

as we can see that the value of BASE is 0F0H and by adding 13 we get OFDH. And this value is nowhere used.

Comment: BASE is the first I/O address of the "CPU Support card".  It apparently has multiple functions, with different I/O address assigned to each function.  This card apparently has parallel port "DATA" and "STAT" registers as the thirteenth and fourteenth I/O addresses of the card. That corresponds to offsets of 12 and 13 from card's first I/O address. Adding 12 and 13 to the 0F0h gives the I/O address parallel DATA and STAT registers. If the BASE address is changed then the calculated AUXSTAT and AUXDATA address are automatically updated to reflect this, without having to edit these values.

Comment: The AUX ports defined there are then used in [`AUXIN`, `AUXOUT`, `AUXLP`](https://github.com/microsoft/MS-DOS/blob/master/v1.25/source/IO.ASM#L598).

Comment: It appears that AUXSTAT and AUXDATA are likely used in a file named `AUXIO.ASM` that wasn't included in the "MS-DOS:2.00:SCP Tarbell OEM" source code files you're looking at.   Note that this source code isn't for MS-DOS itself, but for an OEM port of MS-DOS to a computer that isn't IBM PC compatible.